# How to create@Query with named parameters for date between to_date format in Spring Data JPA

Tags: sql, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have created below query in Spring Data JPA, while running the application I'm not getting any result when using this code

If I commented between date comparison then rest of the query is working fine. Problem with only "v2.MSG_TIME between to_date(:fdate, 'DD-MON-YYYY hh24:mi') "
                + "and to_date(:tdate, 'DD-MON-YYYY hh24:mi')"

```
@Query(value = "select * from Employee v1, Department v2 where v1.EMP_HDR_OID = v2.EMP_HDR_OID "
            + "and v2.MSG_TIME between to_date(:fdate, 'DD-MON-YYYY hh24:mi') "
            + "and to_date(:tdate, 'DD-MON-YYYY hh24:mi')     "
            + "and v1.RESN_FOR_RPT_CODE='10' and v1.LOCO_ST_CODE='2'",nativeQuery=true)

List<Employee> findCustom(@Param("fdate") String fdate, @Param("tdate") String tdate);
```

I'm getting the following log output when running the application:

```
Hibernate: select * from PTC_LOCO_POS_RPT v1, PTC_EMP_HDR_PART v2 where v1.EMP_HDR_OID = v2.EMP_HDR_OID and v2.MSG_TIME between to_date(?, 'DD-MON-YYYY hh24:mi') and to_date(?, 'DD-MON-YYYY hh24:mi')     and v1.RESN_FOR_RPT_CODE='10' and v1.LOCO_ST_CODE='2'
[]
```

Can anyone please help me is that date comparison is correct? Is there any other way?
using `@Query` or named parameters.

Comment: See if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27823370/jpa-select-query-with-timestamp-and-date-fields-fail-to-retrieve-results helps

Comment: What is the problem? why do you think this should return any data?

Comment: @JensSchauder - I don't know how to pass the :fdate and :tdate in JPA. What I mentioned is not correct it seems. what is the right approach for query creation in spring data jpa ?

Comment: I what sense is it not correct? What do you expect and how is it different from what you get? So far you have just shown a SQL statement that looks perfectly fine to me.